How to separate hyperlinks from the hyperlinked scripts
Given this list of 15 documents, I like to extract each one of the titles of 15 documents, document number, date of approval, date of activation, and the clickable hyperlink. Thereafter, represent the data as a dataset.
The following gives the list of hyperlinks, from which I can select the desired ones:
Import["https://lex.uz/en/search/nat?query=food%20safety", "Hyperlinks"]

Likewise, I like to get the titles and link them to the hyperlinks and so on. But I want to do all these operations at once.
Any idea about a standard extraction method for this task.
